# Promo code for in app purchase items

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, sqlite, app-store

Apple doesn't provide promo codes for in app purchase products.  My content will be in an sqlite database in the app.  I'll use a column flag to indicate purchase status.  Once the user purchases, I unlock the row by changing the flag.

Would it be easy enough to provide another interface so the user can enter in a code and unlock the item without purchasing?  If the user then tries to purchase a product they have used a code for, I query the row for purchase status and display an alert that the user already has this item...or simply indicate this in my app's in-app store.

Does this sound feasible/doable?  Possible Apple would reject this technique?

Answer (score 5):

I think Apple would reject you if you duplicated the in-app store functionality in your app.  the reason they would not allow it is that it circumvents the way they make money off of the in-app purchases, and there is no distribution guarantee (how could Apple guarantee that you deliver the content as promised?)